# Usage of YouTube and LinkedIn URL schemes in iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, linkedin-api, url-scheme

I'm trying to open the YouTube app from our own application.  I'm doing this with the following code:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://?????"]];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtube.com/user/..."]];
}
```

If the youtube app is available open it with the given URL else open the web version of YouTube.  Now my question is what do i need to put in place of the question marks to open an  user account / profile page in the YouTube app? I already tried to fill in youtube://user/username but that does not work.

And I have exactly the same question for the LinkedIn app.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://?????"]];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.linkedin.com/company/...."]];
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To open a user page on linkedin you can use:

`linkedin://#profile/<profile_id>`

I could not get it to work with a profile name, only with the numeric ID. Also, I could not get this to work with companies, just with people.

Answer (score 0):

The correct formatting of the link is:  `youtube://www..youtube.com/user/username`

(Edit note: I suspect the two periods after www is a typo, but I'm not an expert - someone who is please remove this note and fix if needed).